# Relation between multiple hierarchical taxonomies linked to a single entity

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I am working on an online test application which supports multiple choice questions.

I have created schema for taxonomy (classification) system to be used with questions.

```
taxonomy(id, name, slug, description)
taxonomy_terms(id, taxonomy_id, name, slug, parent, weight)

question_taxonomy(id, question_id, taxonomy_term_id)
```

A question is classified under various categories (taxonomies).

At the top rests `Exam` taxonomy which has `Subject` taxonomy as children. Each `Subject` consists of various `Topic` taxonomy which may further be divided into Sub Topics by adapting `Sub Topic` taxonomy.

To create relationships between various taxonomy terms(linked across taxonomies), I have created another table as

```
taxonomy_term_relations(id, parent_id, child_id)
```

e.g,

`MAT` is a taxonomy term for `Exam` Taxonomy

`MAT` may have two subjects viz `Reasoning` & `General Knowledge` which are taxonomy terms for `Subject` taxonomy

`Reasoning` subject will have 10 different topics with taxonomy terms falling under `Topic` taxonomy, say `Reasoning` will have `Topic A`, `Topic B` ....

Each `Question` will belong to a `Topic` which in turn will belong to `Subject` which again will belong to `Exam`.

A `Subject` may belong to multiple `Exam`s or a `Topic` may belong to multiple `Subject`s.

Is this the correct approach to create db schema for this system.

#### UPDATE

@MirNazim suggested another approach to this problem with `Exams`, `Subjects` and `Topics` treated as separate entities rather than taxonomy, which will reduce the complexity of whole thing. So the new structure may become

```
exams(id, name, description...)
subjects(id, name, description ...)
exam_subjects(id, exam_id, subject_id)
topics(id, name, parent, weight....)
subject_topics(id, subject_id, topic_id)
```

Any suggestions on this approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Taxonomy -> TaxonomyTerm
TaxonomyTerm -> Subject
Subject -> Topic
Topic -> Question
```

Each of these lines is a 1 to many relationship, e.g. A single Taxonomy can have 1 or more TaxonomyTerms, and these terms can be related to multiple Taxonomies. I think you mostly have it but I'm not seeing a need to link one TaxonomyTerm directly with another.

Comment: How do you suggest to maintain relations between taxonomy terms. The need for linking one taxonomy term to another is that it is terms which are linked to each other and not taxonomy. Taxonomy is an abstract relationship whileas taxonomy terms define the actual relation between terms of different taxonomies.

How do you see it differently. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I can find all TaxonomyTerms which share a common Taxonomy or Subject. Perhaps this does not mean they are directly related. Within the example you provided there were not multiple TaxonomyTerms directly related so I assumed you misspoke at some point. Should you need to directly relate them you have the correct idea of a relation table, a table with two foreign keys to the TaxonomyTerm table, one for each term